# Prove $2^{m-1} > \log(m)$?

Tags: inequality

How can I prove this inequality for all natural numbers $m>0$?

$$2^{m-1} > \log(m)$$

Comment: Even $\;m-1>\log m\;$ ...

Comment: i know, but i don't know how to prove it. i tried by l'hopital, but, i get it with espilon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $2^{0}>\log(1)$.

Now assume $2^{m-1}>\log(m)$.

Then $2^{m}>2\log(m)=\log(m^2)>\log(m+1)$, since $m^{2}>m+1$ for every $m \ge 2$, and $\log$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume here that you don't know any "deep" inequality about $\ln(x)$ such as $\ln(x) < x -1$, and will do a simple proof by induction on $m$ :

- Base case $m=1$ : $2^0 > \ln(1)$, true.
- Assume true up to $m$, then :
  $$
  \ln(m+1) = \ln\left(m(1+ \frac1m)\right) = \ln(m) + \ln(1+\frac1m ) \overset{(*)}{<} 2^{m-1} + \ln(1+\frac1m ) < \\
  2^{m-1} + \ln(2) \overset{(**)}{<} 2^{m-1} + 2^{m-1} = 2^{(m+1)-1}
  $$

$(*)$ Inductive hypothesis.

$(**)$ Clearly for $m \geq 1,\ \ 2^{m-1} \geq \ln(2)$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a graphical proof.
- Curve with blue represents $2^{m-1}$
- Curve with red represents $log(m)$